# PhpStorm + Xdebug = page not loading

Tags: php, xdebug, phpstorm

First things first, have some xdebug info:

```
Xdebug installed: 2.2.0rc1
Server API: Apache 2.4 Handler Apache Lounge
Windows: yes - Compiler: MS VC9 - Architecture: x86
Zend Server: no
PHP Version: 5.4.0
Zend API nr: 220100525
PHP API nr: 20100525
Debug Build: no
Thread Safe Build: yes
Configuration File Path: C:\Windows
Configuration File: C:\Uniserver\UniServer\usr\local\php\php.ini
Extensions directory: C:\Uniserver\UniServer\usr\local\php\extensions

You're already running the latest Xdebug version
```

Everything looks fine. This is what my php.ini looks like:

```
[Xdebug]
zend_extension=C:\Uniserver\UniServer\usr\local\php\extensions\php_xdebug-2.2.0RC1-5.4-vc9.dll
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9123
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=0
xdebug.remote_autostart=0
xdebug.remote_log="C:\Uniserver\UniServer\usr\local\php\extensions\tmp\log.log"
xdebug.overload_var_dump=1
xdebug.trace_format=0
xdebug.show_exception_trace=0
xdebug.default_enable=0
```

Now, I'm going to try to debug with PhpStorm. First I go to Settings->PHP->Servers and add this:

```
Name: localhost
Host: localhost
Port: 8080
Debugger: Xdebug
```

(Yes, my website is running on port 8080, otherwise I get conflicts with other software I'm using.) Then I create a new Run/Debug configuration:

```
PHP Remote Debug
Name: local
Servers: localhost
Ide key(session id): PHPSTORM
```

I also create a start/stop debug bookmark with this tool: http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/marklets/index.html

Ok, everything looks ready, so I hit the Debug button in PhpStorm.

The homepage of my project is located at http://localhost:8080/Project/page/Home.php, so I navigate there. The page loads. I hit the start-button in my bookmarks bar, reload and the page stays blank...

When I add a breakpoint on the home.php file in my project and reload again, the breakpoint gets hit! I can step over, step into,... All the values are displayed.. This works without any issue. But when I went over all the breakpoints, or hit Resume Program, and return the the browser the page is completely blank. The HTML code looks like this:

```
<html><head><style type="text/css"></style></head><body></body></html>
```

What is going on? Why is the page I'm debugging not being rendered? Stepping over the code works, all the php and html is being executed, yet in the end nothing is shown in my browser. I plan to use the Xdebugger on a function that is located in a file /Project/class/Account.php, but I can't get there without pressing a button on my Homepage.

Why not use an Xdebug proxy you say? Might that solve anything? Well, whenever I try to set one up I get this error:

Xdebug proxy: Cannot connect to xdebug proxy on 'localhost:9123'

Even though my Xdebug proxy configuration is correct:

```
IDE key: PHPSTORM
Host: localhost
Port: 9123
```

Can anyone please tell me what's going on? I really need this debugger because there's a certain function that won't work correctly for some reason, and it's driving me insane. I need to check what variables are being passed and what's happening to them.

**EDIT**

Extra information: When I'm done stepping over all the code my debugger says:

```
Waiting for incoming connection with ide key 'PHPSTORM'
```

Might this be the reason my page is not loading?

**EDIT EDIT**

Ok, instead of hitting the debug button, I can also just start listening to PHP Debug Connections. This works as well! My breakpoints are hit, I can step into... But the same problem persists: My webpage stays blank and my debugger says 'Disconnected' at the end. The problem persists in any browser.

**EDIT EDIT EDIT**

I've found out something else that's very weird while debugging... I can step into my code just fine until I hit the function that gets my database instance. The Database class looks like this:

```
class Database
{
    private static $instance = null;
    private static $conn;

    private function __construct()
    {
        try {
            self::$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'database', '3308');
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            $errorpager = new CustomPageGenerator();
            $errorpager->generateErrorPage("Connection to database failed. Please try again later.");
        }
    }

    public static function getInstance()
    {
        try {
            if (self::$instance == null) {
                self::$instance = new Database();
            }
            return self::$instance;
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            $errorpager = new CustomPageGenerator();
            $errorpager->generateErrorPage("Connection to database failed. Please try again later.");
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function query($sql)
    {
        try {
            return self::$conn->query($sql);
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            $errorpager = new CustomPageGenerator();
            $errorpager->generateErrorPage("Connection to database failed. Please try again later.");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I get this feeling my database class might have something to do with this issue... Every time I hit the getInstance() function, debugging halts abruptely and I get the net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET error in Google Chrome. Could this be the issue?

Comment: "Even though my Xdebug proxy configuration is correct:" -- I don't think so. Do you know xdebug proxy is for? Do you have xdebug proxy installed/running? -- I'm confident "no" will be an answer.

Comment: Don't know who reported this, but: http://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=810

Comment: For latest versions, you can find additional config info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20730943) <br>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you describe, xdebug remote debugging works.

Why that HTML is returned to the browser (and not what you expect) is hard to say. Have you tried using a stable version of xdebug?

Comment: This is the only version I got working after a few hours of messing around. I'm glad I even got this far...

Comment: Hmm, probably you messed around too much and have destroyed something. I suggest you set it up new from scratch after you have documented a half-working configuration.

Comment: But what is there to set up? All you have to do is edit the php.ini to point to the correct dll... But ok, will try to use a previous xDebug version.

Comment: Nope, just as I said: this is the only version of xdebug that's working... All the others do nothing.

Comment: As said: Completely uninstall xdebug and PHP and re-install it from scratch. As written: You have now documented your (broken but half-way working) configuration. You can now re-start from scratch, taking care that the setup is quick, fresh and well-done. Additionally to better track problems, put your PHP configuration under version control.

Comment: Ok, will try that. In the meantime: added a bit of extra info.

Comment: hakre: I think I may have found out what the issue could be. Could you check my Edit Edit Edit please? Thanks.

Comment: @Matthias: Please take a look if you have this bug: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61079 - This was fixed *after* the release of PHP 5.4.0.

Comment: This really doesn't make any sense to me. I've got no issues with my website whatsoever. But when I hit the debug button nothing loads anymore, YET debugging works perfectly UNTIL I hit my Database class...

Comment: Explanation: When there is a debugging, internals of the program are made visible. That's an additional process. That what has been made visible is then transferred over the wire so that your IDE can display variables contents. Imagine there is a bug which makes PHP crash in the process of making it visible. Like we had it for simplexml elements: http://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=746 - it's just that then PHP dies, things go wrong - just because of debugging. That's all.

Comment: The problem can be a bug with the debugger, or the PHP objects of mysqli. As there is some reports with var_dump() (that is making things visible like a debugger, too) I assume there is a bug with PHP. Grab yourself a trunk version and check if the problem disappeared.

Comment: @Matthias Try debugging **very simple page first**, like this: `$a = 5; $b = 3; $z = $a + $b; echo $z;`. If it's working .. then it's something else (xdebug bug, php crashing etc -- as @hakre suggested).

Comment: @Matthias I also suggest: install latest **stable 5.3** branch; the same for xdebug (not RC but 2.1.x **stable**) and try debugging there.

Comment: Did some testing on a different computer. Older, stable version of PHP and Xdebug works indeed. Will just use those for the moment or wait for a fix.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is fixed in Xdebug 2.2.0RC2. Please upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

- Symfony 2
- PhpStorm 4.0.1

I have upgraded to php_xdebug-2.2.1-5.4-vc9.dll and this solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was because xdebug was listening at an ipv6 port only and the browser tried to connect via ipv4 (localhost).

I'm not sure what it depends on if the debug server binds to an ipv4 or ipv6 port. In my case it's with Ubuntu 12.04 and php stuff from default Ubuntu repository.

You can check if you have the same issue by running

```
sudo netstat -tulpen
```

while phpstorm is waiting for a connection.
Look for an entry for port 9000 (or whatever you configured).
In my case the output then contains the line

```
tcp6       0      0 :::9000                 :::*                    LISTEN      1000       6687897     318/java
```

It's possible to solve this by changing kernel settings, but the solution I took was to just connect to this ipv6 port:
In phpstorm's run/debug configuration used for that project, in server settings I changed Host from "localhost" to "ip6-localhost". In Ubuntu that's the ipv6 counterpart (::1) of localhost (127.0.0.1), by default configured in /etc/hosts.
Again, I'm not sure of that also applies to other operating systems.