# How to integrate Xdebug 2.2.3 (PHP 5.53) with PhpStorm 7.0

Tags: php, google-chrome, mamp, xdebug, phpstorm

How do I integrate Xdebug 2.2.3 (PHP 5.53) with the new PhpStorm 7.0?

The official documentation doesn't provide a step-by-step process.

Comment: **1)** http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Configuring+PHP+Environment **2)** http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Debugging+PHP+Applications **3)** http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2013/07/webinar-recording-debugging-php-with-phpstorm/

Comment: I've written two large articles about LOCAL and REMOTE xdebugging with PHPStorm: [How to setup and use XDEBUG with PHPStorm 6/7 (locally in Windows 7/8 and Mac OS X)](http://www.dev-metal.com/setup-use-xdebug-phpstorm-locally-windows-78-mac-os-x/) and [How to debug code on a remote server (or in vagrant box) with PHPStorm](http://www.dev-metal.com/debug-code-remote-server-vagrant-box-phpstorm/). The remote version needs improvements, but does the job.

Comment: @Andrew Barber Just to add a little more backdrop, the question was self-answered and intended for [sharing](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) with folks who might have encountered similar difficulties.  For e.g. PhpStorm's online doc guided on downloading and installing Xdedug.  However, for MAMP users, Xdebug is available by default - just have to edit php.ini.   Veterans would have figured that out easily.  However, for folks new to IDEs, I hope that by listing out all the steps sequentially and explicitly, without having to customise settings, it would have helped.

Comment: @Panique Thank you for your excellent article.  Examples and screenshots are great and definitely helpful.  Have added your article to the list of references at the question part.

Comment: @LazyOne The webinar was great.  If I had watched that earlier, I would have moved on to IDEs earlier and saved more productive time.

Comment: This question is currently [being reviewed on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214828/186381).  Feel free to contribute your views on the question there.

Comment: here is an excellent tutorial that explain step by step procedure
https://hubpages.com/technology/Local-PHP-Debugging-with-XDebug-Atom-and-XAMPP

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**My default setups**

1. MAMP 2.2.  Installation directory is "default".
2. Phpstorm 7.0.  The basic config are done as per guided by the online doc.
3. A Phpstorm project has been setup with sample codes ready for debugging.
4. Chrome browser is used.  Feel free to contribute if you would like to share on other browsers.

**Configuring php.ini in MAMP to enable Xdebug**

1. Open /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/conf/php.ini.
2. Do remember to open the correct directory corresponding to the php ver of your choice.  So if you want to use other versions, then note the corresponding version s/n such as /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php(**corresponding version number**)/conf/php.ini.
3. Go to last line and delete ";" before "zend_extension" to uncomment the line.
4. Next, add this line below "xdebug.remote_enable = 1".
5. The result should look like this:

   ```
   [xdebug]
   zend_extension="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php(**corresponding version number**)/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-(**some numbers given.  Do not change**)/xdebug.so"
   xdebug.remote_enable = 1
   ```

**Check if Xdebug is successfully enabled**

1. Restart your MAMP server.
2. From Chrome, run "localhost:8888/MAMP/phpinfo.php".
3. You should be able to find somewhere down the line for the Xdebug header.  The first table row should show xdebug support > enabled.
4. Note that xdebug.remote_enable table row should show "on".
5. Note the port number of xdebug.remote_port.  It should be "9000" by default..
6. Note the IDE Key.  Eventually, it should show "PHPSTORM" when you have successfully config Xdebug.
7. To avoid complicating the config process, we are using all default values and directories.  Once you've successfully configured and test driven the debugging feature, I reckon that it'll be easier to tune and customise your config.

**Configuring PhpStorm 7.0**

1. Open PhpStorm.
2. Goto Menubar > PhpStorm > Preferences > Project Settings > PHP.
3. Reconfirm that you have config the "PHP language level" and "Interpreter" to your required PHP version.
4. Click on "..." to open up a popup window.
5. Under "PHP home", once again click on another "..." to open another window.
6. Choose the correct PHP version via the Finder .
7. For the default installation folder, it's at applications > MAMP > bin >php > php5.5.3(choose your version) > bin > click ok.
8. Back at the previous popup window, you should see PhpStorm being able to detect the PHP version and the corresponding Xdebug ver.  In my case it is PHP version 5.5.3 and Xdebug 2.2.3.
9. Next, goto Menubar > Run > Edit Configutions > click "+" at top left-hand corner > PHP Web Application.
10. Next, goto Menubar > PhpStorm > Preferences > Project Settings > PHP > Debug > DBGp Proxy.
11. The "IDE Key" should show "PHPSTORM" as default.
12. The "port" should show "9000" as default.1. Add Name.
13. Choose current server from drop down menu or:
14. Click on "...".

    - "Host" = localhost.
    - "Port" = 8888.
    - "Debugger" = Xdebug.
    - "Browser" = Chrome or any you would like (need to use corresponding browser debugging extension).

**Installing Chrome's Xdebug Helper**

1. From Chrome, find Xdebug Helper and download + install it.
2. You should see a grey bug icon at Chrome's address bar, right side.
3. Right click on Bug icon > options > IDE Key > Dropdown menu > choose "PhpStorm" > close browser tab.
4. Left Click on Bug icon > Debug.

**Ready for Testdrive**

1. Now, from your PhpStorm's opened project, click on the "listen" icon.  It's the icon with telephone icon + and "stop icon" + "Bug icon" all in one button.  It's two buttons to the right of the debug button.  The "stop icon" should disappear and replaced by a signals icon.
2. Next, choose a few break points on your sample code
3. Now, when you click on the debug button, Chrome should automatically open a new tab with your sample code/app running and suspended at your break point or point where you've configured to suspend at runtime by default.

**Additional config: Administering Database right from PhpStorm**

It's time to pop the champagne unless you want to do further setup to manage your database from within PhpStorm, which is another reason why IDE is great.  You can refer to PhpStorm's very own online doc [here](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Installing+and+Configuring+MAMP+with+PhpStorm+IDE).

Just to elaborate further on few of the procedures as mentioned in the doc that I thought might be helpful, here it goes:1. In PhpStorm, if you can't find the vertical "database" button at the right-hand-side, then simply click on a small button at the bottom-left-most corner.  The button looks like a monitor icon.  Doing that will toggle the vertical "database" button visible.

1. Click on the vertical button of "database".
2. Press COMD + N.
3. From the dropdown menu, select new datasource.
4. Under the first tab "Database" > JDBC driver files > select MySQL Connector/(some ver) > "Click here to download".
5. At "Database URL", note that your url comprises:

   ```
   jdbc:mysql://localhost:8889/hello_database 
   where
   "hello_database" is the name of your database.
   8889 is the port number to your MySQL server.  Once again, 8889 is the default
   ```
6. Config your database access credentials.
7. If you don't have any existing db, then goto PhpMyAdmin to manually setup a new db and create new users with access credentials.
8. Now back in PhpStorm, simply key in the same access credentials.
9. Once your configurations are done correctly, you should see the database window populated by a list of your db tables.
10. You can now manage your db directly from PhpStorm without having to do it separately from PhpMyAdmin.

**Summary**

The above steps are pretty lengthy, and this is the reason why I thought it might be helpful to some of you who might encounter some difficulties in the configurations.  On the same note, if I have missed out any important steps, please feel free to add your comments.  Hope this helps.

Update: Php5.53 seems to have a bug that does not allow Chrome to page-reload properly.  For example, when I changed

```
from <?php echo 'Hello'?>
to <?php echo 'Hello Dale'?>
```

the word "Dale" does not refresh and appear on Chrome.  My cache is disabled for dev just like any others would and I even tried Cache Killer for good measure.  Finally, when I rolled back to php5.4.19 with it's corresponding Xdebug config, the refresh issue was no longer present.  Let me know if you have a work around.  Meanwhile, I'll have to make do with Php5.4.19.

Comment: I would like to add that PHPStorm 7 support "config-free" LOCAL xdebugging. If xdebug is installed correctly (usually done with one click or one bash line), just show PHPStorm the path to your php executeable. Done ;)

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your lists. You need a space between the- and the text following it

Comment: @JDB Thank you for the edit and clearer listing style.

Comment: Thi tutorial 
https://hubpages.com/technology/Local-PHP-Debugging-with-XDebug-Atom-and-XAMPP help me a lot

Answer (score 1):

PHPStorm 8.0 (availabe thru EAP) fully integrates remote debugging (over SSH), including Vagrant boxes.

http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2014/04/php-remote-interpreters-support-in-phpstorm-8-eap/#more-7367

Comment: here is an excellent tutorial that explains step by step procedure
https://hubpages.com/technology/Local-PHP-Debugging-with-XDebug-Atom-and-XAMPP